# Unable to collect links of different properties from a webpage

Tags: vba, web-scraping, queryselector

I've written a script in vba to get only the links of different properties under the title `Single Family Homes` from the right sided area of a webpage. When I run my script, I get nothing, no error either. The content I wish to grab are static and available within page source, so `XMLHttpRequest`should do the trick.
Although it seems the selectors I've defined within my script is errorless, I can't still fetch the links of different properties.

[Webpage address](https://www.zillow.com/homes/for_sale/33125/house_type/12_zm/0_mmm/)

I've written:

```
Sub GetLinks()
    Const link$ = "https://www.zillow.com/homes/for_sale/33125/house_type/12_zm/0_mmm/"
    Dim oHttp As New XMLHTTP60, Html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim I&

    With oHttp
        .Open "GET", link, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .send
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        With Html.querySelectorAll("article > a.list-card-info")
            For I = 0 To .Length - 1
                Sheet1.Range("A1").Offset(I, 0) = .item(I).getAttribute("href")
            Next I
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Expected links are like:

```
https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/3446-NW-15th-St-Miami-FL-33125/43822210_zpid/
https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/1877-NW-22nd-Ave-Miami-FL-33125/43823838_zpid/
https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/1605-NW-8th-Ter-Miami-FL-33125/43825765_zpid/
```

***How can I get all the links of different properties from it's landing page from the link above?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the class of the child alone. Note there are a number of other things I would like to change about the code but know you like to keep your structure/style.

```
Sub GetLinks()
    Const link$ = "https://www.zillow.com/homes/for_sale/33125/house_type/12_zm/0_mmm/"
    Dim oHttp As New XMLHTTP60, Html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim I&

    With oHttp
        .Open "GET", link, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .send
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText

        With Html.querySelectorAll(".list-card-info")
            For I = 0 To .Length - 1
                Sheet1.Range("A1").Offset(I, 0) = .item(I).getAttribute("href")
            Next I
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Some of the changes I might make:

```
Private Sub GetLinks()
    Const LINK As String = "https://www.zillow.com/homes/for_sale/33125/house_type/12_zm/0_mmm/"
    Dim http As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim i As Long, links As Object

    Set http = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60: Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    With http
        .Open "GET", LINK, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Set links = html.querySelectorAll(".list-card-info")

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For i = 0 To links.Length - 1
            .Cells(i + 1, 1) = links.item(i).href
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Damn, QHarr!!! It worked out. You can surely bring about changes if those are ideal to follow.

Comment: There is something wrong with the html of the page. I know there is at least one stray closing img tag. If you look at the article tags one of the closing tags are faded as if there is an error somewhere.

Comment: I'm still curious to follow the improved version of the above script that you have suggested. Thanks.